# "hinunter" vs "nach unten"

Tags: word-usage, preposition, synonym

I've heard that both "hinunter" and "nach unten" means "downwards". They both mean a direction (while lone "unten" means a location).

What is the difference between them?

Comment: These words are far from having a similar meaning. What did your research at dictionaries tell you, and what didn't you understand? _nach_ makes the difference regarding the location.

Comment: [This link](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=de&text=downward) includes both words. Maybe I should have written "hinunter" instead of "runter" but [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/runter) it says that "runter" is just a contration of "hinunter".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [Here](https://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,33275) it says specifically that they are synonymous. From experience I know, that answers here give bigger insight. But I suppose word questions are now frowned upon?

Comment: I am still not clear about what you don't understand. _unten_ is a location. combinatons indicate a direction to that location.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ From what I know, **unter** is a location, while **hinunter** is a direction. **runter** can mean both (so I edited the question). Am I mistaken?

Comment: _"it says specifically that they are synonymous."_ You probably asked the wrong question. _hinunter_, _runter_ and _nach unten_ are synonymous.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, sorry. I confused "hinunter" and "runter". I thought you could use it interchangeably.

Comment: _"runter can mean both"_ No _runter_ never means a specific location. Where did you get that from?

Comment: I linked to dictionary in the second comment. Firstly, it says that "runter" is a contraction of "herunter" *and* "hinunter". So they should mean the same...

Comment: OP is right and you're wrong @πάνταῥεῖ. *Ich gehe nach unten*, *Ich gehe hinunter* und *Ich gehe (he-)runter* can all mean the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the context, these two terms are relatively synonymous. 
The main difference is that *hinunter* explicitly expresses a move away from the speaker. The opposite would be *herunter* - a move towards the speaker.

Comment: While this might be the definition you find in a dictionary, I think many Germans are unaware of this and colloquially use these two words as they please.

Comment: <trying to be funny> Swabians distinguish between directions depending on the position of the narrator ("naa" and "raa"). But one can argue if that's German at all :-) </trying to be funny>

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: For Bavarian, it's "obi" (hinunter) and "oba" (herunter).