# Kann ich einen Berg herunter klettern? (hin vs her 1. Person Singular)

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Inspiriert von [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56703/hinunter-vs-nach-unten) - Ist folgender Satz im streng logischen Sinne korrekt?

> Ich klettere den Berg herunter.

*herunter* bedeutet eine Bewegung in Richtung der sprechenden Person, während *hinunter* eine Bewegung von der sprechenden Person weg kennzeichnet. (Dass dies im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch oft nicht beachtet wird bitte ich zu ignorieren.)

Nehmen wir an ich bin gerade am klettern, telefoniere und sage diesen Satz. Nach meinem Verständnis bewege ich mich in dem Moment der Aussage von meiner Position weg, müsste also bei einer gerade stattfindenden Aktion immer die hin-Variante nutzen. Ist das korrekt?

Wie steht es damit innerhalb einer Erzählung? Nehmen wir an ich befinde ich im Tal und erzähle davon. Muss ich dann sagen

> Ich kletterte den Berg herunter.

oder

> Ich kletterte den Berg hinunter.

Schließlich erzähle ich gerade von einer Aktion die sich auf meine jetzige Position zubewegt.

Last but not least, was ist, wenn ich am nächsten Tag wieder auf der Bergspitze bin und davon erzähle?

Gilt jeweils die Situation zum Zeitpunkt der Erzählung, die aktuelle oder habe ich die Wahl?

**EDIT**:

Ich denke die Frage kann man auch allgemeiner stellen, ob eine Bewegung in der 1. Person Präsens mit der Vorsilbe *her* möglich ist. Es gibt ja noch viele weitere. Herunter fiel mir halt als erstes ein ^^.

Was die Vergangenheitsformen angeht scheint es (die bisherigen Antworten deuten darauf hin) wohl auf die Sichtweise anzukommen. Evtl gibt es auch Styleguides, bzw Beispiele aus der Literatur um das zu untermauern (also für hin vs her in der 1. Person Singular).

Beim Nachdenken kamen mir zusätzlich folgende Sätze in den Sinn

> Ich ging die Treppe hinauf.
>
> Ich kam die Trepp herauf.

Mein Sprachgefühl, sagt mir, dass beide richtig sind. Beim zweiten die hin-Variante aber nicht funktioniert. Ist dem so?

Comment: Die Frage ist sehr gut, zumal die Interpretation hin = zum Sprecher hin und her = vom Sprecher weg bei der ersten Person Singular (Ich) schwierig zu interpretieren ist. Ich würde Deiner Darstellung so folgen (auch wenn ich behaupte, dass im täglichen Gebrauch kaum ein Mensch einen Unterschied zwischen beiden macht)

Comment: Isses nicht umgekehrt: "her..." wie in "komm her(unter)", "hin" wie in "ich gehe hin(unter) ? So kenn ich's. DWDS beschreibt das hin- auch so, der Duden das her-. Es ist wohl ein hin und her :-)

Comment: ja, habe es genau verdreht... Sorry

Comment: Die Frage so wie du sie jetzt umformuliert hast, ist nicht zu beantworten, denn "gehen" und "kommen" sind "converse verbs", die sich auf zwei verschiedene Perspektiven beziehen. Wenn du beides noch mit "hinauf" und "herauf" mischst, gibt es nur 'Cocktail ;-). Mit erster Person hat es nicht unbedingt zu tun.

Comment: Very curly topic! A while ago, I found this interesting topic on SpiegelOnline: "Nach oben hinauf und von oben herunter" - https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-nach-oben-hinauf-und-von-oben-herunter-a-341697.html.  Don't know whether it addresses OPs question directly, so posting it as a comment.

Comment: @mtwde "Ich ging die Treppe hinauf. Ich kam die Trepp herauf. Könntest du vielleicht einen Zusammenhang für die zwei Sätze liefern bzw. eine mögliche Fortsetzung für sie? Ich hab da 'ne Idee, aber sie ist noch sehr vage...

Comment: Hä, war hier nicht ein Bounty auf die Frage gesetzt? Was ist mit dem passiert?

Comment: @äüö gute Frage ...

Comment: @äüö: [Der Historie nach](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/56750/revisions) ist die Bounty nach acht Tagen regulär ausgelaufen. Sie wurde nicht manuell vom Auslobenden vergeben und auch nicht automatisch, da keine der Antworten seit Auslobung eine positive Wertung erreicht hat. Kann natürlich sein, dass da dennoch ein Fehler passiert ist, aber von meiner Warte sieht alles normal aus.

Comment: @äüö: [Es gibt anscheinend Probleme mit Bounty-Benachrichtigungen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345862/255554).

Answer (score 5):

Sehr interessante Frage, die meiner Meinung nach beantwortet werden kann, indem man den Begriff von "mental spaces" von Gilles Fauconnier in seinem gleichnamigen Werk anwendet ([siehe hier](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/mental-spaces/990994C4CD82B3F34DAB8504E1999E10)) Bezogen auf eine Erzählung im Nachinhein gibt es zwei Varianten mit unterschiedlichem Fokus.

Mit **hinunter** versetzt du dich in deine gestrige Position zurück und legst mental erneut die Strecke zurück Schritt nach Schritt (du weißt noch nicht, wann du ankommen wirst etc). Du bist nur Handelnder. Dann würdest du das so erzählen: "Stell dir mal vor: Gestern kletterte ich gerade den Berg hinunter und fragte mich plötzlich, ob ich es überhaupt noch schaffen würde".

Mit **herunter** nimmst du "nur" deine heutige Position ein als Zuschauer dessen, was du gestern gemacht und erreicht bzw. vollzogen hast. Du beobachtest als Zuschauer das Ergebnis deines Handelns.

Comment: Bitte neben dem Link auch direkt in der Antwort zitieren.

Comment: Es geht aber auch einfacher: "Sie kommt herunter" und "ich gehe hinunter" ganz bodenständig im Hier und Jetzt. Im normalern Sprachgebrauch wird aber auch das hin- und her öfter vermischt.

Comment: @a_donda Es ging um die Frage, was man benutzt, wenn man Vergangenes erzählt. Das steht auch ganz klar im OP genauso wie das, was du eben schreibst.

Comment: Es geht um beides, jetzt ("bin gerade") und gestern.

Comment: "Nehmen wir an ich bin gerade am klettern, telefoniere und sage diesen Satz. Nach meinem Verständnis bewege ich mich in dem Moment der Aussage von meiner Position weg, müsste also bei einer gerade stattfindenden Aktion immer die hin-Variante nutzen." Die Frage mit dem gerade war schon im OP beantwortet. Die Hauptfrage war das Berichten im Nachhinein ("Wie steht es damit innerhalb einer Erzählung?").

Comment: Da fällt mir ein daß in Teilen Norddeutschlands man nicht gefragt wird "Wo kommst du denn her ?" sondern "Wo bist du denn wech ?". Nur so, am Rande :-) Und nach etwas mentalem hin und her habe ich mich entschieden, dem Gedanken mit +1 meine Zustimmung zu geben.

Comment: @Nico Ich habe sie nicht wirklich beantwortet, sondern frage auch, ob meine Vermutung richtig ist :) . Evtl kannst du etwas auf diese mental spaces eingehen. Der Link führt ja nur zum Buch, bzw welcher diese Fokusse ist sozusagen in Erzählungen der Standard? Oder kommt es wirklich immer auf den Einzelfall an?

Comment: @mtwde Fauconnier ist Psychologe, und der Kern seines Werkes ist, dass der Mensch eine und dieselbe Situation aus verschiedenen Perspektiven konstruieren kann, was zum Teil auch zu Konflikten führen kann. Meine Antwort oben war nur eine Anwendung seiner Theorie auf sprachliche Phänomene. Ein weiteres Beispiel könnte das Englische mit seiner Verlaufsform sein. "Yesterday I was reading when my neighbour came to see me" (Perspektive von gestern) vs. "Yesterday I read a book and had visit from my neighbour" (Perspektive von heute). Die Passivkonstruktion ist auch so ein Fall.

Answer (score 0):

Im Folgenden werde ich explizit die beiden Orte *Berg* und *Tal* verwenden.

Nehmen wir zunächst an, *ich* sei der Sprecher, der etwas über *jemand anderen* berichte. Wo würden Sie den Sprecher der folgenden Sätze, also mich, verorten?

1. *Jemand* kletterte vom Berg ins Tal *herunter*.
2. *Jemand* kletterte vom Berg ins Tal *hinunter*.

Satz 1. würde ich aussagen, wenn ich mich als Sprecher im Tal befände, wohingegen ich Satz 2. aussagen würde, wenn ich mich als Sprecher eben nicht im Tal, sondern irgendwo anders befände. Unsere erste Erkenntnis lautet: Die Verwendung von *herunter* und *hinunter* ist vom Ort des Sprechers abhängig.

Nun ändern wir die Situation, indem *ich* als Sprecher über *mich selbst* berichte.

3. *Ich* kletterte vom Berg ins Tal *herunter*.
4. *Ich* kletterte vom Berg ins Tal *hinunter*.

Wenn wir ganz analog zu den ersten beiden Sätzen vorgehen, so würde ich Satz 3. aussagen, wenn ich mich als Sprecher im Tal befände, wohingegen ich Satz 4. aussagen würde, wenn ich mich als Sprecher eben nicht im Tal, sondern irgendwo anders befände. Wieder ist die Verwendung von *herunter* und *hinunter* vom Ort des Sprechers abhängig. Ob der Sprecher dabei über sich selbst berichtet, ist unerheblich.

Betrachten wir nun den Satz

> *Ich* klettere gerade den Berg ins Tal *herunter*.

Wie zuvor deutet die Verwendung von *herunter* darauf hin, dass ich mich als Sprecher im Tal befände. Allerdings steht diese Information, die zum Kontext dieser Sprechsituation gehört, nun im Konflikt zum Inhalt des Satzes. Nach dem sei ich ja eben nicht im Tal, sondern gerade dabei, auf einem Berg herumzuklettern. Ein Satz, bei dem Kontext und Inhalt nicht im Konflikt stehen, ist

> *Ich* klettere gerade den Berg ins Tal *hinunter*.

Answer (score 0):

> *herunter* bedeutet eine Bewegung in Richtung der sprechenden Person

Die Prämisse ist falsch. Schon das DWDS drückt durch Einklammerung aus, daß die Bedeutung "in Richtung des Sprechers" optional ist.

> von (dort) oben nach (hier) unten ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/herunter))

Das DWB ist expliziter.

> 3) minder scharf ist die bedeutung ausgeprägt, wenn der erste bestandtheil des wortes *her* nicht zur geltung kommt, und *herunter* nur so viel wie unterwärts, abwärts sagt ([DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=herunter))

Zitiert wird Goethe.

> Und den blauen Rock, der vielgefaltet vom Busen
>   Reichlich herunterwallt zum wohlgebildeten Knöchel. ([Zeno](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Goethe,+Johann+Wolfgang/Versepen/Hermann+und+Dorothea/Klio.+Das+Zeitalter))

Siehe auch unter [herab](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=herab) mit Beispielen wie

> die Haare, Schultern hingen herab

Der Ausgangssatz kann daher so gelesen werden, daß es nur um eine Bewegung nach unten geht, ohne daß eine Aussage über den Standort des Sprechers gemacht wird.

Comment: DWDS schreibt unter Etymologie "her Adv. ‘von dort (nach hier)’, die Richtung auf den Standpunkt des Sprechers zu bezeichnend (im Gegensatz zu hin), bzw. Punkt 1 "von (dort) oben nach (hier) unten", sehe da gerade nicht, dass es optional ist. DWB sagt auch direkt als erstes "von der höhe nach der tiefe zu einem sprechenden entgegen". Ich bin mir auch nicht sicher was scharf und minder scharf bedeuten sollen.

Answer (score 0):

Im Sinne von vom Berg ins Tal ist in einer Präsensbewegung der ersten Person ''herunter'' und ''herab'' tatsächlich unsinniger als ''hinunter'', ''hinab'', ''bergab'', ''abwärts'' oder (wieder) "runter", aber aus der Perspektive ''erdnäher als beim vorigen Schritt'' oder "dem Volk aufs Maul geschaut'' ist ''ich klettere herunter'' definitiv tolerabel,würde ich behaupten.

Answer (score 0):

In "herunter" und "hinunter" stecken die Bewegungen "hin" und "her" drin, und diese werden zusätzlich mit dem "-unter" als Bewegungen von oben nach unten präzisiert.

Für "herunter" gibt es 2 Möglichkeiten:

1. Jemand sagt "Kletterst du mal zu mir herunter!?", weil das gewünschte Ziel mit seiner Position (=Referenzposition) übereinstimmt. In dem Fall klettert man herunter (zu ihm).
2. Jemand sagt "Kletterst du mal da herunter!?", weil einfach das gewünschte Ziel unten ist. Es spielt hier keine Rolle, ob der Auftraggeber mit oben ist oder sich unten befindet; es geht einzig darum, als Ergebnis der Handlung unten zu sein. Auch in dem Fall klettert man herunter.

Auch bei "hinunter" gibt es 2 Fälle:

3. Jemand sagt "Kletterst du mal dorthin hinunter!?", weil das gewünschte Ziel nicht mit seiner Position (=Referenzposition) übereinstimmt. In dem Fall klettert man den Berg hinunter.
4. Jemand sagt "Kletterst du mal hinunter?", weil es ihm um den Vorgang geht, also um das Klettern, den Abstieg selbst. Auch hier klettert man den Berg hinunter.

Der "Jemand", also der Auftraggeber, kann auch nur gedanklich existieren, d.h. man stellt sich dann selbst nur vor:

- ob das Ziel mit einer gedanklichen Position übereinstimmt
- ob es um ein Endergebnis oder um die Handlung an sich geht

Es kommt also auf den Kontext an, wenn man sich entscheidet für "Ich klettere den Berg herunter" oder "Ich klettere den Berg hinunter". Beides ist möglich, je nachdem was man sich dabei gedacht hat.

---

Du kannst also im Tal sagen "Ich kletterte den Berg herunter", wenn du zum (evtl. auch nur gedachten) Auftraggeber hingelangt bist oder es dir bei der Aussage einfach nur auf das Ergebnis ankommt. Du kannst auch im Tal sagen "Ich kletterte den Berg hinunter", wenn du vom (evtl. auch nur gedachten) Auftraggeber nach woanders hin den Berg abgestiegen bist oder es dir nur auf die Handlung des Hinabgehens ankommt bei deiner Aussage.

Am nächsten Tag, wenn du wieder oben auf dem Berg bist, kannst du genau die selben Dingen sagen, da alle Voraussetzungen dafür trotzdem noch stimmen. Weiterhin kannst du aber auch den Referenzpunkt für deine Aussage auf deine neue Position, die Bergspitze, setzen und nun zusätzlich "Ich kletterte den Berg hinunter" sagen, wenn du damit meinst, dass du von deiner heutigen Referenzposition zur gestrigen Zielposition (nämlich unten ins Tal) gelangt bist.

---

Zu "Ich kam die Treppe hinauf":

Hier sehe ich keinen Widerspruch, d.h. man kann das ohne weiteres so sagen für den Fall, die gedachte Zielposition ist oben und der Referenzpunkt ist unten. Oder für die Verdeutlichung des Vorgangs des Hochgehens ist das auch so OK.

Answer (score 0):

> Ich **ging** die Treppe **hin**auf.
>
> Ich **kam** die Treppe **her**auf.

Hier sieht man gut den Gegensatz *gehen - kommen*, der nur mittelbar abhängig vom Sprecher ist. Noch elementarer:

> Darf ich hinein (gehen) ? (zu einer Person vor der Tür)
>
> Darf ich herein kommen ? (zur Person im Raum)

Das ***Klettern*** ist ein gemeiner Spezialfall der Bewegung. Eigentlich betont man mehr die Technik als die Fortbewegung, nicht nur beim *bouldern* (=hin- und herklettern). Nach unten tut sich der Experte eher abseilen, oder absteigen. Das Hinaufklettern (auf Bäume und Felsen) ist eher den Affen vorbehalten. Und irgendwie lernt man als Kind, dass Klettern das eine ist, Runterkommen was anderes (gerade weil man nicht einfach *hinunter*klettern kann).

In der geschilderten Situation wäre runter das normale Wort: hochklettern vs. runterklettern.

**"Ich klettere jetzt runter"**

Das würde passen, wenn ein Nicht-Alpinist einen heiklen Abstieg in Angriff nimmt. Oder ein Kind von einem Spielgerüst. Damit legt man sich nicht fest, was "hier/dort" ist, bzw. der Bezugspunkt bleibt offen.

---

Zeno

Ich kann mir ein Kleid, das von einer bestimmten Stelle aus **hin**unterwallt (bis an eine andere heran), auch gut vorstellen. Das würde gut zu den *vieldurchlöcherten Schwämmen* Homers passen. Es suggeriert eine Aktivität.

---

Herunterwirtschaften

Irgendwie ganz human, dass man nicht **hin**unterwirtschaften kann. Es ist also ganz natürlich, wenn sich etwas Überdurchschnittliches bald wieder zu uns herunter gesellt.

So wie "Komm mal wieder (he)runter"

---

runter

duden.de:

> umgangssprachlich für herunter, hinunter
>
> *runter vom Baum!*

Also da könnte ich jetzt einwenden: was jetzt? Wenn ich im Baum sitze, und will allein sein, dann kann ich doch sagen *geh hinunter* oder *geh runter*. Das "r" kann also für "hin" ODER "her" stehen.

---

Das ist schon interessant: auf Schweizerdeutsch gibt es uffe-abe für hoch-runter. Wobei "unten" einfach "unde" ist. Frz. und engl. haben jeweils eigene "Lösungen", um Ort und Richtung zu unterscheiden.

### Fazit

Das Kleid darf sowohl herunter- als auch hinunterwallen. Je nachdem von wo (inkl./exkl.) bis wo (inkl./exkl.) kann das eine oder das andere noch besser sein.

Beim Klettern passen diese Richtungsvorsilben eher nicht. Da gibt es anderes Vokubalar, auch für Laienbewegungen in den Bergen.

Zum *Kriechen* schon eher: zur frechen Hausschlange kann man sagen **"Du kannst gleich wieder hinunterkriechen vom Sofa"**, weil man es ja auch wörtlich meint.